# AccountManager: invalidateAuthToken does not invalidate the token

Tags: java, access-token, accountmanager

I'm trying to get a brand new token from a Google account stored in a Android device but all that I got is the same old token that I've been caching in the last days. It seems that it's cached somewhere in the phone, and even the Internet request is not being sent (I made the test in the app without Internet connection and the same token is returned).

I used the `invalidateAuthToken` method before getting a new one with `getResult` from `AccountManagerFuture`. Take a look please:

```
public String updateToken(Activity activity) throws Exception {             
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(activity);
    Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");

    if (accounts == null || 
        accounts.length == 0 || 
        "".equals(accounts[0].name.trim())) 
    {
        throw new Exception("Não há contas Google configuradas no smartphone.");
    } 
    else if (!"crsilva@gmail.com".equals(accounts[0].name.trim()) && 
             !"cristiano.bezerra@sulamerica.com.br".equals(accounts[0].name.trim()) &&
             !"tholiver@gmail.com".equals(accounts[0].name.trim())) 
    {
        Log.w("Util.updateToken","conta obtida: " + accounts[0].name);
        throw new Exception("Conta Google não autorizada.");
    }
    Log.w("Util.updateToken","conta obtida: " + accounts[0].name);
    am.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", null);
    Log.w("Util.updateToken","Passou do invalidateAuthToken");
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = 
        am.getAuthToken(accounts[0], "ah", null, activity, null, null);
    Log.w("Util.updateToken","Passou do getAuthToken");
    Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
    Log.w("Util.updateToken","Passou do getResult");
    future = null;
    am = null;
    accounts = null;
    String authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
    Log.w("Util.updateToken","Token: " + authToken);
    return authToken;
}
```

A thread called this method from a Util class by singleton instance. The manifest has all the permissions necessary.  Does somebody have idea why the token is not refreshed?

Answer (score 7):

To invalidate the auth token you need to pass the token you want to invalidate as the second argument to invalidateAuthToken. Please see section "4.4.3 Invalidate the auth token" of [this blog post](http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2012/05/android-account-manager-part-i.html). The video on that page is also helpful.

The documentation for [invalidateAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#invalidateAuthToken%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) mention that the second argument may be null, but this only mean that it's allowed to call this method with null, not that every cached token is invalidated if null is passed.

If you do something like this instead your code should work:

```
// Get token
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = am.getAuthToken(accounts[0], "ah", null, activity, null, null);
Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
String authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

// invalidate the token since it may have expired.
am.invalidateAuthToken("com.google", authToken);

// Get token again
future = am.getAuthToken(accounts[0], "ah", null, activity, null, null);
bundle = future.getResult();
authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

Answer (score 6):

It is simpler to simply "peek" the currently cached token, check if it is still valid, and create a new one if required.

```
String authToken = accountManager.peekAuthToken(account, Constants.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE);
// validate the token, invalidate and generate a new one if required
accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE, authToken);
accountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account,
                Constants.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, NOTIFY_AUTH_FAILURE);
```

Comment: According to the documentation of peekAuthToken this can only be used by the Authenticator of the account (or someone else sharing the same UID): "This method requires the caller to hold the permission AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS and to have the same UID as the account's authenticator.". So it's impossible to use this for google accounts

Comment: as @nibarius mentioned - this throws java.lang.SecurityException: uid XXXX cannot peek the authtokens associated with accounts of type: com.google